# Code-Heavy ViewModels in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm writing an application in WPF and found myself loving whole MVVM paradigm. My only concern at the moment is that my ViewModels are becoming **heavy**. They contain `Commands`, logic to enable and disable buttons, instances of other ViewModels, async method with `DispatchTimer` timers etc. Is this something that is normal in this kind of development environment? Or is there some logical way of organizing ViewModels without becoming too "crowded"?

Comment: When I see downvotes without any explanation... I guess when you hit a roadblock, you hit it hard.

Comment: 1. Divide the view to smaller. 
2. Create more classes to manage the content of different responsibilities. 
3. Use the lightmvvm framework to reduce redundant codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `ViewModel` is just an adapter between your `model`, where logic and data live, and the `view` which is shown to the user.

The idea is you can easily swap views or change them, without the logic suffering from that.

Having said that, depending on the complexity of your application, they might grow quite big, but if it's mainly stuff that ends up enabling/disabling stuff on your view, and isn't doing logic / processing stuff, I'd say this is where it's supposed to live.

Comment: Gotcha, this pretty much clarified it all. If it deals with the view, regardless of its size, it should remain there.